# Add a button to react material-table toolbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to add a button to material-table toolbar. it doesnt do anything relevant to the table. it just opens a modal with some information

I want to add a button called "quotations" to the left side of the "add item" button.

[image]

Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-yalow-4pnk4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Please provide the code or a codesandbox

Comment: @v1s10n_4 Here is the sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-yalow-4pnk4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 4):

As **Will Evers** mentioned, it's possible to add whatever is necessary to `Toolbar` of the `MaterialTable` component by using `Toolbar` prop :

```
          Toolbar: (props) => (
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
                alignItems: "center"
              }}
            >
              <Button
                style={{ height: "fit-content" }}
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
              >
                Quotations
              </Button>
              <div style={{ width: "13rem" }}>
                <MTableToolbar {...props} />
              </div>
            </div>
          ),
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mtable-toolbar-button-9oqrj?file=/src/App.js:485-1053)

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs, it looks like you need to override the Toolbar component of your table and you should be able to add what ever you want above the column headers:

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0mqf.png

Comment: i don't want to add anything to the column headers.  I want to add another button next to "add item" button. I can override toolbar and add another button like in https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2048 using divs. I want to know whether there is a different way to do it.

Comment: you wouldnt be, you would be editing the component that sits above the columns

Answer (score -1):

Use this prop in the  component tag

```
renderTopToolbarCustomActions={() => (
    <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size="large"
        onClick={() => console.log('something')}
    >
        Quotations
    </Button>
 )}
```